# Storing noncopyable but movable object in std::function

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a functor s, which is noncopyable but movable, how can I store it in a std::function? i.e, how to make the following code compile? (using gcc 4.6)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
  S() = default;
  S(S const&) = delete;
  S& operator=(S const&) = delete;
  S(S&&) { }
  void operator()() { }
};

std::function<void()> func;

void make_func()
{
  S s;
  func = std::bind(std::move(s));  // This won't compile
}

int main()
{
  make_func();
}
```

Comment: that won't work because `s` is local and goes out of scope...

Comment: `std::function<>` doesn't contain the callable object it wraps (I'd assume precisely to _avoid_ requiring them to be me movable/copyable).

Comment: It is possible if you redesign your code and you are able to *initialize* `std::function`. For example this works `S s; std::function<void()> func(std::ref(s)); func();`. But you also have to make `s` not to go out of scope before `func` which means it has to be global in some sense. But still you *can* store a movable object in `std::function` (with restrictions) if that is your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the standard, `std::function` is supposed to be copyable.  Therefore, you cannot *directly* achieve what you want.

You can get away with some custom wrapper I'd guess, though.  It would go something like this:

- make your wrapper contain an `std::shared_ptr` to the actual functor;
- when a wrapper is constructed from a functor rvalue, move the functor to dynamically allocated memory;
- copy constructor for the wrapper and destructor are simply handled by `shared_ptr` copy-ctor/destructor;
- `operator()` for the wrapper dereferences the smart pointer to the real functor and delegates to `operator()` on it.

Comment: Exercise for the reader? Implement this generically using variadic templates and perfect forwarding of argument types.

Comment: Thanks doublep, that meets my current need.