# How to store non-copyable std::function into a container?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, move

I want to store callbacks in a vector or another container in C++11.

One way to do so would be to store a vector of std::function.
This works well for lambda or std::bind with copyable arguments.

However, if there is one non copyable (movable only) argument, it will fail due to the conversion from the lambda/std::bind internal type to the std::function...

```
#include <vector>

class NonCopyable {
public:
    NonCopyable() = default;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable &&) = default;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> callbacks;
    callbacks.emplace_back([] {});

    NonCopyable tmp;
    callbacks.emplace_back(std::bind([](const NonCopyable &) {}, std::move(tmp)));
    // When converting the object returned by std::bind to a std::function,
    // a copy of the arguments happen so this code cannot compile.
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to move std::bind arguments into the std::function instead of copying them?

Comment: `std::function` requires the functor it wraps to be CopyConstructible, so you are out of luck.

Comment: So is there a better pattern to store callbacks? Like packaged_task or another class?

Comment: Store pointers to the functions or functors, perhaps?

Comment: You may be able to use a `std::reference_wrapper<NonCopyable>`, which you can then put into the `std::vector<std::function<...>>` container.

Comment: I investigated this (with c++14 lambda captures, custom Functor object) and  it looks like the problem is at `std::function`, not at container or at bind. `std::function` can't hold a non-copyable object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944635/storing-noncopyable-but-movable-object-in-stdfunction So you can't use `std::function`.

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843271/passing-a-non-copyable-closure-object-to-stdfunction-parameter , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768273/why-cant-c11-move-a-noncopyable-functor-to-a-stdfunction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::ref` and `std::cref` are meant to be used in this cases to avoid copying the object (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Not sure that I got your question right, but this compiles for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class NonCopyable {
public:
  NonCopyable() = default;
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
  NonCopyable(NonCopyable &&) = default;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> callbacks;
    callbacks.emplace_back([] {});

    NonCopyable tmp;
    auto fun = std::bind([](const NonCopyable &) {}, std::cref(tmp));
    callbacks.emplace_back(fun);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, be careful about the life cycle of the referenced variable!

Comment: I think he want to store the fun with the tmp and call the fun later. Your code can compile, but the tmp will be freed when he call the fun. Think about change the main() to add_callbacks() and call the callbacks in another function.

Comment: Yup, your comment in not special to this case though, but it's more a general statement about variables that go out of scope :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::shared_ptr`, which is copyable. Something like

```
using ptr = std::shared_ptr<NonCopyable>;
callbacks.emplace_back(std::bind([](const ptr &) {}, ptr(new NonCopyable())));
```

This way NonCopyable object will auto destruct on callbacks destructor.